# Should using VGA output be degrading performance and framerate?

Tags: xbox-360, performance

I stoped playing my Xbox 360 on HDMI because I connected it with a PC monitor which doesn't have HDMI, it only has VGA.  I already know that I will not have that image quality, but the problem I faced is different.  The performance or the framerate was very very low in some highly detailed games like GTA V.

Is there a difference between HDMI and the original port of the Xbox 360 in regards to performance and framerate?

Comment: its normally up to the monitor as far being able to keep up with the medium of both 360 and cable

Comment: Would an Xbox 360 maybe be tailored to the framerate of a TV instead of that of a monitor?

Comment: More like a t.v's framerate may be between 2ms to 5ms, and your monitor is probably 8ms for refreshing the screen. Did you also go to system settings, display and set your display higher than 640×480(If you do this and your screen goes black, don't touch anything for around 15 seconds and it will return automatically)(or if that doesn't work; hold Y plus left trigger while starting up the Xbox to reset the display settings).

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector#Cable_quality

says

> The same VGA cable can be used with a variety of supported VGA resolutions, ranging from 640×350px @70 Hz (24 MHz of signal bandwidth) to 1280×1024px (SXGA) @85 Hz (160 MHz) and up to 2048×1536px (QXGA) @85 Hz (388 MHz)

so your cable and monitor are likely to support high frame/refresh rates, at least 1080p@60